# javascript json node w/ special char

Tags: javascript, json, char

so i am trying to parse some json yahoo finance data
i created this just for testing
but the special char ^ cannot be accessed...
how do you access the json node with special characters
i tried the bracket notation but did not work
with the ["^GSPC"] as suggested but get an error
get Unexpected token ^

```
var market={"^GSPC":{"symbol":"^GSPC","end":1604001600,"start":1603978200,close:[3330.69,3327.8,3308.83]}}
console.log(market.^GSPC)
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try using the bracket notation `market["^GSPC"]` ?

Answer (score 0):

since json key is the special character, you should access using bracket notation, rather than dot.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties

```js
var market={"^GSPC":{"symbol":"^GSPC","end":1604001600,"start":1603978200,close:[3330.69,3327.8,3308.83]}}
console.log(market["^GSPC"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling Object property using `Object.key`, use the square bracket `Object[key]` as follows.

You can call object property using key in two ways.
`Object.key` or `Object[key]`.

```js
var market={"^GSPC":{"symbol":"^GSPC","end":1604001600,"start":1603978200,close:[3330.69,3327.8,3308.83]}}

console.log(market["^GSPC"]);
```